# pytest and parallel program benchmarking

Tags: python, parallel-processing, benchmarking, pytest

I'am using **py.test** module to benchmark two versions of my algorithm and results I'm shown are way lower that those I get when I manually run the program. First variant is reference algorithm, while other improves reference algorithm execution by parallelization. For parallelization I use  `multiprocessing.Process`. Benchmark shows ~4s execution time for parallel version (compared to ~90 sec for sequential), which is great. However, when i run parallel version manually, it takes way more than 4 s (I don't even get to finish execution, my PC overloads (all cores jump to 100% usage in htop) and I am forced to interrupt execution. And yes, I have added `if __name__ == '__main__'` part before creating processes.

I have timed first variant with time.time() and time.clock() and they both show around 100 sec (which is still higher than pytest shows, but as executin time depends on initial random setup, this might be understandable).

I've searched in documentation but couldn't find any explanation why this might happen. Do you have any ideas ? Is py.test even good way to benchmark parallel program, and do you have any other suggestions ?